# Want to end for loop in RTF template BI Publisher after 10 iterations

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I Want to end a for loop in RTF template after 10 iterations. Can someone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
<record_set>
<record>
<rownum>1</rownum>
<transaction_id>111</transaction_id>
<amount>200</amount>
</record>
<record>
<rownum>2</rownum>
<transaction_id>222</transaction_id>
<amount>300</amount>
</record>
<record>
<rownum>3</rownum>
<transaction_id>333</transaction_id>
<amount>400</amount>
</record>
<record>
<rownum>4</rownum>
<transaction_id>444</transaction_id>
<amount>200</amount>
</record>
</record_set>
```

**Option 1**

You can use a variable in an if statement.

```
<?for-each:record_set?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'row_number',1)?>
<?for-each:record?><?if:xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,'row_number')<=2?>
Transaction ID: <?transaction_id?>
Row Number: <?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,'row_number')?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX,'row_number', xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,'row_number')+1)?>
Amount:<?amount?>
<?end if?>
<?end for each?> 
<?end for each?>
```

**Option 2**

You can add a `rownum` to your select statement and XML, then use that in the for-each condition.

```
select rownum, transaction_id, amount from your_table

<?for-each:record_set?>
<?for-each:record[rownum<=2]?>
Transaction ID: <?transaction_id?>
Row Number: <?rownum?>
Amount:<?amount?>
<?end for each?> 
<?end for each?>
```